# How to print out data using java iterator with a linked list

Tags: java, linked-list, iterator

I am trying to iterate over the MylinkedList using the MyLinkedListIterator class I created. I am expecting it to print out drop, goofy, Donald, Duck, Mouse etc... but the while loop that I wrote is not working properly. I tried debugging by system.out.print(iter.next()) expecting the first element to be printed in the linked list "drop" but instead was returned null.

```
public class xxx_xxx_xxxx{
    
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    
            
            MyLinkedList<String> list = new MyLinkedList<>();
    
            list.add("drop");
            list.add("goofy");
            list.add("Donald");
            list.add("Duck");
            list.add("Mouse");
            list.add("Kangaroo");
            list.add("Koala");
            // initialized list of MyLinkedListIterator
            MyLinkedListIterator<String> iter = new MyLinkedListIterator<String>();
    
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                System.out.print(iter.next());
            }
    
        }
    
    }
    
    interface MyList<E> {
    
        public void insert(int index, E object) throws Exception;
    
        public void add(E object);
    
        public E get(int index) throws Exception;
    
        public int indexOf(E object);
    
        public int lastIndexOf(E object);
    
        public E remove(int index) throws Exception;
    
        public E set(int index, E object) throws Exception;
    
        public int size();
    
    }
    
    class Node<E> {
        E element;
        Node<E> next;
    
        public Node(E element) {
            this.element = element;
        }
    }
    
    class MyLinkedList<E> implements MyList<E>, Iterator<E> {
        Node<E> head = null;
        Node<E> tail = null;
        int size = 0;
    
        @Override
        public void insert(int index, E object) throws Exception {
            if (index < 0 || index > size - 1)
                throw new Exception("Invalid index.");
    
            Node<E> newNode = new Node<>(object);
    
            Node<E> current = head;
            int counter = 0;
            Node<E> previous = null;
            while (counter < index) {
                previous = current;
                current = current.next;
                counter++;
            }
    
            if (previous != null)
                previous.next = newNode;
            newNode.next = current;
    
            size++;
    
            if (index == 0)
                head = newNode;
            if (index == size - 1)
                tail = newNode;
    
        }
    
        @Override
        public void add(E object) {
            Node<E> newNode = new Node<E>(object);
    
            size++;
    
            if (head == null)
                head = newNode;
            else
                tail.next = newNode;
            tail = newNode;
    
        }
    
        @Override
        public E get(int index) throws Exception {
            if (index < 0 || index > size - 1)
                throw new Exception("Invalid index.");
    
            Node<E> current = head;
            int counter = 0;
            while (counter < index) {
                current = current.next;
                counter++;
            }
    
            return current.element;
        }
    
        @Override
        public int indexOf(E object) {
            Node<E> current = head;
            int index = 0;
            while (current != null) {
                if (object.equals(current.element))
                    return index;
                current = current.next;
                index++;
            }
            return -1;
        }
    
        @Override
        public int lastIndexOf(E object) {
    
            int result = -1;
            Node<E> current = head;
            int index = 0;
            while (current != null) {
                if (object.equals(current.element))
                    result = index;
                current = current.next;
                index++;
            }
    
            return result;
        }
    
        @Override
        public E remove(int index) throws Exception {
            if (index < 0 || index > size - 1)
                throw new Exception("Invalid index.");
    
            Node<E> current = head;
            int counter = 0;
            Node<E> previous = null;
            while (counter < index) {
    
                previous = current;
                current = current.next;
                counter++;
            }
    
            if (previous != null)
                previous.next = current.next;
            E result = current.element;
    
            size--;
    
            if (index == 0)
                head = current.next;
            if (index == size - 1)
                tail = previous;
    
            return result;
        }
    
        @Override
        public E set(int index, E object) throws Exception {
            if (index < 0 || index > size - 1)
                throw new Exception("Invalid index.");
    
            Node<E> current = head;
            int counter = 0;
            while (counter < index) {
                current = current.next;
                counter++;
    
            }
    
            E result = current.element;
            current.element = object;
            return result;
    
        }
    
        @Override
        public int size() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return size;
        }
    
        public Iterator<E> iterator() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return new MyLinkedListIterator();
        }
    
        @Override
        public String toString() {
    
            String result = "[";
            Node<E> current = head;
            while (current != null) {
    
                result += current.element;
                if (current.next != null)
                    result += ", ";
    
                current = current.next;
            }
            return result + "]";
        }
    
        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }
    
        @Override
        public E next() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }
    }
    
    //Create the class MyLinkedListIterator<E>, which implements the Iterator<E> interface.
    
    class MyLinkedListIterator<E> implements Iterator<E> {
    
        // MyLinkedListIterator should contain the following data items,
    
        // "list" of type MyLinkedList
        MyLinkedList<E> list = new MyLinkedList<>();
    
        // "currentNode" of type Node<E>, initially set to list.head
        Node<E> currentNode = list.head;
    
        // The hasNext() method should return true as long as currentNode is not null
    
        public boolean hasNext() {
    
            return currentNode != null;
    
        }
    
        // The next() method should return the list's data item at currentNode, and
        // advance currentNode
    
        public E next() {
    
            Node<E> res = list.head;
            currentNode = list.tail;
            return (E) res;
    
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: There is far too much going on in your code that simply doesn't work. What are you trying to achieve, are you simply making your own implementation of a linked list? If so then in addition to the corrections commented on the answer below, `MyLinkedList` should not implement `Iterator`, it should instead implement `Iterable`? And only `MyLinkedListIterator<E>` should implement `Iterator<E>`. See an example here of how implementing iterator could work: https://gist.github.com/jnwhiteh/68d095c630dfcaddffd1

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with `next()`.  One that you immediately set the `currentNode` to the very end of the list, which is probably why you are getting null as the second element if I'm guessing correctly.

```
currentNode = list.tail;
```

Think about this.  You have a linked list.  What is the *next* element after the current one?  It is not the tail...

Comment: I apologize if this answer is novice but would it be currentNode.next  ?

Comment: Yes, the next method should have `currentNode = currentNode.next;`. also this line is problematic `Node<E> res = list.head;`, and will cause the next method will ALWAYS return the `list.head`, instead it should be changed to `Node<E> res = currentNode;` to return the current node of the iterator.

Comment: You're awesome, thank you!

Comment: @AndrewAmirzadeh Just note also that this line `MyLinkedListIterator<String> iter = new MyLinkedListIterator<String>();` simply creates a new iterator with no list/elements. It is not tied to your list in any way, so it will always return null because you create an internal empty list `MyLinkedList<E> list = new MyLinkedList<>();` Instead try `MyLinkedListIterator<String> iter = list.iterator();`

Comment: I kept going through all the fixes and now I'm getting this: Cannot read field "next" because "this.currentNode" is null. Do I need to make a construtor? I thought by default a constructor is made with one blank.

Comment: @AndrewAmirzadeh If you want to correctly implement an iterator then you should not create a constructor, rather you need to fix the problems with your `MyLinkedList` class. See my comment to your question with some details.